# Expected value of product of sinusoids

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

> In the book *Adaptive Signal Processing* by Widrow, an equation (2.20) on page 23 is presented without proof as:
>
> $$E \left[ x_k x_{k-n} \right] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1} ^{N} \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi k}{N}\right) \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi (k-n)}{N}\right) $$
>
> $$ = \frac12 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi n}{N}\right);\quad  n = 0, 1 $$
>
> where $N>2$ is an integer, $n\in\{0,1\}$, and $x_k = \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi k} N\right)$.

I have been trying to figure out how the above equation was simplified, but my trig is fairly rusty... any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is a convention in mathematics that a symbol should mean the same thing wherever it occurs in an equation. So how is the $k$ on the left side related to the $k$ on the right side?

Comment: k is a time index, such that $x _{k-n}$ is a time delayed version of $x _k$. That is, $x(k) = \sin(2 \pi k / N)$, so the equation on the right is summing the product x(k) * x(k-n) and then dividing by N, where N is some integer that represents the number of samples per period.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - while your comment is generally correct, $k$ is a dummy variable on the right, and may similarly be a dummy variable on the left (I would need to know more about how the LH expression is defined to know for sure). Two dummy variables do not have to be unique if used in unrelated expressions. And the meaning of the LH expression is actually immaterial to his question, which is about the 2nd equation.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I disagree, especially when the fix is so simple; just change the $k$ on the right side to $i$ or $j$ or $\ell$ or $m$, etc. The point of the whole question is the assertion that the LHS -- which is an autocorrelation function and has two arguments ($k$ and $k-n$ in this instance) -- actually depends not on the two arguments separately, but on their difference ($n$ in this instance). This is what makes the  needless appearance of $k$ on the RHS especially jarring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spent a day reviewing one of my old textbooks:

$$
E[x_k x_{k-n}] = \frac{1}{N} \sum ^N _{k=1} \sin \left( \frac{2 \pi k}{N} \right) \sin \left( \frac{2 \pi (k-n)}{N} \right)
$$

Using the product to sum identity:
$$
= \frac{1}{2N} \sum ^N _{k=1} \left[ \cos \left( \frac{2 \pi n}{N} \right) - \cos \left( \frac{2 \pi k + 2 \pi (k-n)}{N} \right) \right]
$$

The left term is constant, giving:
$$
= \frac12 \cos \left( \frac{2 \pi n}{N} \right) - \frac{1}{2N} \sum ^N _{k=1} \cos \left( \frac{4 \pi k - 2 \pi n}{N} \right)
$$

Actually I was stuck here for quite some time, which was why I posted the original question, but it seems so obvious now: as k increases, the cosine will be sampled at equidistant points along one period, for exactly one period. Therefore the whole sum is equal to 0, just as if I were to integrate under the curve, which leaves:

$$
E[x_k x_{k-n}] = \frac12 \cos \left( \frac{2 \pi n}{N} \right)
$$