# Derivation of $\sum_{k=1}^N \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi (k-n)}{N}\right) =\frac{1}{2}\cos \left(\frac{2\pi n}{N}\right)$

Tags: geometry

Why is it that$$\sum_{k=1}^N \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi (k-n)}{N}\right) =\frac{1}{2}\cos \left(\frac{2\pi n}{N}\right)$$
For $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ and $N>2$?
I tried to solve this using $\sin A \cos B$ formula, but couldn't get the result equal to the right hand side term. I kindly request to help me solve the equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: Are you sure this identity holds for the stated values of $n$ and $N$? It doesn't seem to be true for the choice $n = 1, N = 3$, for instance.

Comment: There is an error in your formula that should have $\dfrac{N}{2}$ instead of $\dfrac12$ on the RHS.

Comment: You will find an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1418860) in the context of signal processing.